# VBA for aligning the pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

I am using an VBA to generate the Pivot Table.

I wanted to Center align my values in the Pivot table, I used the follwing line, in my code, I am getting object required error.

I researched in net, and everywhere it is the same, that we use

> DataLabel.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Below is the code, i am using to generate my Pivot table and trying to align the data values in the cell Center, Could someone suggest, where i am going wrong and how i could correct it.

```
Sub sum2017()
Dim ws9 As Worksheet
Dim pc9 As PivotCache
Dim pt9 As PivotTable
Dim ct9 As Integer
Set ws9 = Sheets("Sum2017")
Set pc9 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "'Result'!R1C1:R1048576C6")
Set pt9 = pc9.CreatePivotTable(ws9.Range("A3"))
pt9.AddDataField pt9.PivotFields("Overdue"), "Sum of Overdue", xlSum
pt9.AddDataField pt9.PivotFields("OK"), "Sum of OK", xlSum
pt9.AddDataField pt9.PivotFields("Total"), "Sum of Total", xlSum
pt9.AddDataField pt9.PivotFields("Overdue %"), "Sum of Overdue %", xlSum
pt9.AddDataField pt9.PivotFields("OK %"), "Sum of OK %", xlSum
ws.pt9.PivotSelect "Sum of overdue", xlDataOnly
DataLabel.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Mikz, what part exactly of the `PivotTable` you want to Center align ? is it the values inside the `xlSum` ? is it the Headers ? what exactly ? each one refers to another `PivotTable` property

Comment: You should use `Option Explicit` with you code.

Comment: @ShaiRado I want to align the values inside the Pivot table to Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will align your `PivotTable` to the center.

```
pt9.TableRange2.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
```

If you want to align only certain part of your `PivotTable`, you can use the code below with combining the `Offset` and `Resize` commands.

Comment: Which you mean "V", i am not able to understand

Comment: @Mikz I meant which answer you accepted as "ANSWER" (there can be only one)

Comment: I accepted your answer, and found the other answer was also useful .

Comment: @Mikz  it's ok , I just explained to you the differences in answers.

Comment: oh. thank you, now i understood, what you ,mean.. Thnak you again :)

Comment: how do i use Offset, if i just want my values in row B , C and D to be aligned Center.

Comment: can you provide one example for using Offset and restore?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148394/discussion-between-mikz-and-shai-rado).

Answer (score 1):

Pivot table fields can be centre aligned in the same way as regular cells.

For example if your pivot table is populating cells A3:C5 you would do as follows:

```
Range("A3:C5").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
```